# Retrieving Explorer's frequent documents list in Windows 10

Tags: windows, explorer, app-id

The following code retrieves Explorer's list of frequently-used folders in Windows 8 (error checking removed for clarity):

```
CComPtr<IApplicationDocumentLists> pDocList;
pDocList.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ApplicationDocumentLists);
pDocList->SetAppID(L"Microsoft.Windows.Explorer");
CComPtr<IObjectArray> pArray;
pDocList->GetList(ADLT_FREQUENT, 0, IID_IObjectArray, (void**)&pArray);
```

This does not work in Windows 10. `pDocList` is valid, and `pArray` is valid, but the array contains no items even though there is stuff in the Explorer jump list.

I tried retrieving the recent (instead of frequent) documents list, but that doesn't work either, although in this case it's `GetList()` that fails.

Does anyone know what happened here? Has the app ID for Explorer changed?

Comment: This is an abuse of the `SetAppID` method. You are supposed to set it to your own app id, not somebody else's. Using it to snoop on somebody else's app id is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

Just set the `cItemsDesired`.

`pDocList->GetList(ADLT_FREQUENT, 99, IID_IObjectArray, (void**)&pArray);`

Answer (score 1):

OK, according to Raymond Chen, a man who certainly knows what he's talking about, we're not supposed to do this, so we won't, and I thank Raymond for his response.

I do, however, have a few comments.

1. The docs are not at all clear that this is the case. For example, the documentation for `IApplicationDocumentLists.SetAppID` says "An application calls the methods of this interface when it wants to retrieve a Jump List's Recent or Frequent list." Note "*a* jump list", not "*its* jump list".
2. It's not hard to imagine cases where it would be helpful to the user if an app could present a list of folders that he's frequently used in Explorer.
3. I don't think it's snooping if we look at the shortcuts in the user's Recent folder. How is this really any different?

Anyway, thanks again for your response, Raymond. We'll find some other way to track frequent folders on behalf of the user.

Comment: The shortcuts in the Recent folder are also not documented. Different versions of Windows organize them differently.